# Why should I compare the balance with BigDecimal.ONE before a transaction in Java?

Tags: java, transactions, compare, bigdecimal, compareto

I'm looking at a tutorial about a financial transaction from an account to another and before transfering the amount from an account to another they do these 2 comparations:

```
fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 1
                && fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(amount) == 1
```

I understand that they do the second comparation to compare the balance with the amount, but what I don't understand is why they compare the balance with BigDecimal.ONE. Can somebody explain?

I don't understand for what is this comparation:

```
fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE)
```

This is the code:

```
if(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 1
        && fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(amount) == 1
){
    fromAccount.setCurrentBalance(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().subtract(amount));
    accountRepository.save(fromAccount);
    toAccount.setCurrentBalance(toAccount.getCurrentBalance().add(amount));
    accountRepository.save(toAccount);
    Transaction transaction = transactionRepository.save(new Transaction(0L,fromAccountNumber,amount,new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    return transaction;
}
return null;
```

Comment: That test seems unnecessary, but it it is harmless.  Why don't you ask the author of the tutorial?

Comment: This isn't actually a programming question, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a `BigDecimal` greater than conditional signature in java. if your `CurrentBalance` variable datatype is `BigDecimal` then you can't use the normal integer conditional signature like `==` or `>` or `<`. `BigDecimal` `compareTo()` method returns values to determine the `equal`, `greater than` and `less than` operations.

Big Decimal CompareTo() method returns

```
0 : if value of this BigDecimal is equal to that of BigDecimal object passed as parameter.
1 : if value of this BigDecimal is greater than that of BigDecimal object passed as parameter.
-1 : if value of this BigDecimal is less than that of BigDecimal object passed as parameter.
```

If we consider this line

```
fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 1
```

this line can simply means in an integer datatype

```
if(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance() > 1)
```

If I convert both of your conditions in a normal integer datatype operation then it will looks like this.

```
if(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance() > 1 && fromAccount.getCurrentBalance() > amount)
```

visit here to understand `BigDecimal` `compareTo()` operation.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bigdecimal-compareto-function-in-java/